# Maven enable profile for specific pugin only

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-profiles

Is it possible to activate a maven profile only when building a specific plugin/goal?

If so how do you go about configuring this in ~/.m2/settings.xml?

Comment: It would be helpfull if you can elaborate what you like to do and why? May there is an other way to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can (de-)activate plugins through profiles, not the other way around. For all options activating profiles, see:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html